# What certifications are there for Fiber Optic termination and splicing?

Tags: layer1, fiber, design, hardware, optics

As a knowledgeable person in computer networks I have always had an itch for learning how to create custom-length fiber optic cables. So, as a personal goal, I want to get trained and certified in cable termination and splicing. What is a good reputable industry-standard certification to pursue?

I'm located in Los Angeles, so if anyone knows a good place for training please let me know (something that wouldn't break the bank, e.g. community college but I'm open to contemplating others).

Comment: These guys are a non profit with lots of basic information on-line for free: http://thefoa.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not terribly difficult to train yourself, if you care about the **doing**. If you care about **selling yourself** more, BICSI will happily take your money as a certifier. Probably better if you can get your employer to have you certified as continuing education so BICSI can take their money, but if it's not applicable enough to your job, it's not.

When I was teaching myself (for work, but the budget was low) I managed to attend a quasi-local fiber optic conference which had lots of BICSI training classes as part of the offerings (but attendees could attend regardless of affiliation - BICSI members would get their cards stamped [or equivalent] to prove they had kept up with training classes.) I've also done some online training webinars under the same circumstances.

As someone new to fiber optics who had actually read and understood the basic background information, I found that there was very little new content to most of these training sessions (and many of them were not-so-subtle sales pitches for some company's product, yet they were an approved training class.)

I remain unaffiliated with BICSI, but I built a fiber optic network that has been running for 6 years now with few problems, and at a very attractive price for my employer. But I don't have any *certificate* for that...

By the way, if you are talking about "custom length *patch* cables" rather than *fiber in walls* or *between buildings*, I can save you the bother - the industry-wide recommendation is to order those factory made, it's almost always a better cable that's more cost effective. Concentrate on remembering to inspect and clean before every connection, and put your initial educational effort there.

Comment: I like these guys but could not justify the cost of their "introductory course" - looks like they have a session in LA in March. I'm not affiliated, but I have bought stuff from the company they work for: http://fisuniversity.com/curriculum.html I think you can also pick up BICSI credits for their courses if you join BICSI first.

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for, it's 450 dlls. I wanna think it's worth it, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

The standards body, which also provides training and certifications, is [BICSI](https://www.bicsi.org/Default.aspx). You must join BICSI. There are then classes, some offered by BICSI, some offered by approved third parties. You take certification tests as BICSI offers them in various places at various times.